# Having a static variable called as argument

Tags: c#, object, colors, static

I would like to implement a structure which contains a defined color issued from `System.Drawing.Color`. Here is my final code.

```
namespace ColorSystem
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    internal void testfunc(Label lbl, System.Drawing.Color newcolor)
    {
        lbl.BackColor = newcolor;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var getvalue = ColorValues.NormalFont;
        testfunc(label1, ColorValues.NormalFont);
        testfunc(label2, ColorValues.NormalFont2);
    }

}
public static class ColorValues
{
    // Private variable to hold font once instantiated
    public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont{ get{ return Color.AliceBlue;}}//Dynamic
    public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont2 =         Color.AliceBlue;//static ??
}
```

What I still don't get is what the difference between those two lines:

```
 public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont{ get{ return        Color.AliceBlue;}}//Dynamic
 public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont2 =         Color.AliceBlue;//static ??
```

When I look with the mouse I see that.

[image: What interpreter show me]

What is the difference between the cube and the hand? Hand is the (get) so is it dynamic? and the cube is a data in memory... ??

Thanks a lot folks!

Comment: It should work, what exception do you get?

Comment: A word on struct vs class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So reading this article it means that it's better for the memory to have a reference type (class) than a variable type (struct).... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example works, but then you say you want make your method take your `struct ColorValue` as parameter, sure you can do it, but you can't fill `BackColor` of `Label` with your struct, because it is of different type and as you guess you would have to pass instance of your struct as you did in your last example.

So either go with your first example, or with your last, but you have to create instances of your struct.

Regarding memory, if you created 1000 instances of `Form1` you would make 1000 instances of `ColorValue`, but if your `struct ColorValue` will stay as it is, it is only 1 `byte`. Generally memory is not an issue.

Edit: 
What is the difference between the following?

```
public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont{ get{ return        Color.AliceBlue;}}//Dynamic
public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont2 =         Color.AliceBlue;//static ??
```

First one is a property, while the second is a field. Properties have set and get methods, so difference is that trying to get value of property will call get method which will return what you want, while field is direct reference to what you want. It is generally advised to expose only properties and hide fields, reason being, that you cannot (or cannot easily) debug/monitor access to fields, while it is easy to debug access to properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your testfunc should look like this:

```
internal void testfunc(Label lbl, ColorValue newcolor)
{
    lbl.BackColor = newcolor.NormalFont;
}
```

How are you passing in your struct? It should be like so:

```
ColorValue colorstruct;
testfunc(somelabel, colorstruct);
```

Also, consider changing the name of `NormalFont` since its not really a font but a color.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a static class, and have some read-only properties. Only instantiate the colors when they are used, so your class will start out with all nulls (no memory allocated), then as you read/get each property, it will instantiate based on the System.Drawing.Color

```
public static class ColorValues
{
    // Private variable to hold font once instantiated
    private static System.Drawing.Color _normalFont;
    public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont 
    {
        get
        {
            // Only instantiate when needed
            if (_normalFont == null)
            {
                _normalFont = Color.AliceBlue;         
            }
            return _normalFont;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use in your form like:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       testfunc(label1, ColorValues.NormalFont);
   }
```

I tried this

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal void testfunc(Label lbl, ColorValues newcolor)
    {
        lbl.BackColor = newcolor;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testfunc(label1, ColorValues.NormalFont);
    }

}
public static class ColorValues
{
    // Private variable to hold font once instantiated
    public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont{ get{ return Color.AliceBlue;}}
}
/*  public struct ColorValue
{
    public static System.Drawing.Color NormalFont = Color.AliceBlue;
}*/
```

Comment: but if my class Color contains 1000 definitions would it good to put a get for each?? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Remember your ColorValues class will not use any memory until each color is instantiated. Even better might be to just put the get { return Color.AliceBlue } and not even keep a reference to it in a local variable. That way you are basically just "wrapping" a bunch of colors using your own labels. This is basically a theme class.